# How to create a NAT Gateway in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-nat-gateway

So I should create (ideally) 1 NAT Gateway per AZ, associated with a private subnet in each. The NAT Gateway takes an [`allocation_id`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-nat-gateway.html):

> The allocation ID of an Elastic IP address to associate with the NAT gateway. If the Elastic IP address is associated with another resource, you must first disassociate it.

An EIP is attached to either [an Instance or a Network Interface](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eip).

So what all do I need to create to create a NAT gateway?

1. An EIP...
2. ...Associated with an instance or a Network Interface.

What is this instance or Network Interface I associate it with? I don't quite follow.

I am imagining I have a bunch of private subnet webservers that also need access to the internet. Are these webservers the instances they are talking about associating with an EIP? Or what?

Can I just create a NAT Gateway and an EIP and nothing else connecting the EIP to the instance/network-interface?

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "multi-ip" {
  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.main.id
  private_ips = ["10.0.0.10", "10.0.0.11"]
}

resource "aws_eip" "one" {
  vpc                       = true
  # WHAT IS THIS
  # WHAT NETWORK INTERFACE DO I NEED TO CREATE
  network_interface         = aws_network_interface.multi-ip.id
  associate_with_private_ip = "10.0.0.10"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create NAT gateway in VPC console. You specify a **public** subnet for it and existing (or let AWS create it) EIP:

[image]

Then you will have to create a route in your private route table to the NAT create,

[image]

And depending if you've created new route table, you can associated the route table with any private subnet you need:

[image]

Comment: So you don't need to do anything with associating the EIP with a Network Interface or an Instance? The EIP is supposed to be associated with a Network Interface or Instance, so that's where I'm confused.

Comment: @LancePollard No. It will be associated with the NAT automatically, when you create the NAT as on the first screenshot.

Comment: What are _they_ associating the EIP then, some internal instance of some sort? What if I want to create the EIP myself, what do I associate the Network Interface and/or Instance with? I'm specifically looking at that last terraform link, where you can specify a network interface or instance for the EIP.

Comment: @LancePollard Yes, can create EIP yourself. There is `Elastic IP` menu in VPC console for that. And then when you create NAT, you select existing.  The NAT will have network intarface. NAT gateway is managed service, so AWS is managing all these aspects. There are also [NAT instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) where you have to do more staff yourself, as they are not-managed by AWS. Instead, you manage them.

Comment: @LancePollard In terraform you have [nat_gateway](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/nat_gateway), where you also just provide existing EIP.

Comment: Correct, yeah you have like `allocation_id = aws_eip.nat.id`, but that `aws_eip`, it requires a Network Interface or Instance ID, what do I provide there?

Comment: @LancePollard This is [optional](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eip#argument-reference) in `aws_eip`. Basically it will be created un-assocaited. Later when you create `nat_gateway` it will be associated with the nat.

Comment: Ah I see, so you create an unassociated EIP and then when you associate it with the NAT Gateway, it will use some instance or Network Interface provided by the NAT Gateway somehow, okay thank you! PHew I've been wondering this for weeks.